# Read specific columns from excel for python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

array = []
for i in range(2, 9):
    array.append([sheet.cell(i, j).value for j in range(2, 5)])
```

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEU4R.png)

I have this code and it works fine, but it's not doing what I want it to do. It is pulling the data from all the three columns of that excel file (see excel image). I only want it to pull data from column C and column E, and store that as a pair in the array. How to do that? I know there is something like skip columns and skip rows in python, but not sure how to embed that in the code I have.

Comment: array.append([sheet.cell(i, j).value for j in [2, 4]])

Comment: Wow that was easy and quick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using openpyxl :-

```
def iter_rows(ws):
    result=[]
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        rowlist = []
        for cell in row:
            rowlist.append(cell.value)
        result.append(rowlist)
    return result

wb = load_workbook(filename = '/home/piyush/testtest.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
first_sheet = wb.get_sheet_names()[0]
print first_sheet
worksheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

fileList =  (list(iter_rows(worksheet)))
col1 = []
col2 = []

for col in fileList:
    col1.append(col[1])#1 is column index
    col2.append(col[2])#2 is column index

for a in zip(col1,col2):
    print a
    #append as pair in another array
```

using pandas:-

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("/home/piyush/testtest.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df.iloc[:,[col1Index,col1Index]]
```